# Duplicate Windows 7 User Profile to a new user

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, steadystate, default-profile

Is there a way in Windows 7 to copy all Windows user profile information (especially desktop and UI settings, including profile picture) from an existing Windows user to a brand new user.

So let's say I have a user named USER1 and I want to create a new user named USER2 who can logon and have exactly the same user experience and priviledges (ie member of the same User Group), is there a way to do this? If possible I would prefer to not use a tool that I need to install and be something I can do through the native OS (this is a restrictive environment so anything external and not approved will be a problem).

I can't seem to find an obvious way to do this but I have no problem with copying or editing registry settings if that's what it takes.

This is on a standalone system that is not a member of a domain.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default / public profile. If you do this, then all new users on first login will have the default profile applied to their login, you cannot have multiple default profiles.

This document tells you how to do it, but it also includes alot more, so you'll have to read it and follow only the part about the public profile:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24373

It starts on Page 9.

Comment: That sounds promising. I'll try it out and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Please let me know, its been a while since I set one up, its really only 5 minutes of work if you know what your doing. I can do another one if needed

Comment: Will do. I'll read through it tonight and try on my test system tomorrow. I'll update this post then.

Comment: Steadystate was an install, and is no longer supported, this document explains how to simulate steadystate with what is built into Windows 7, part of the requires a new default profile which will give you what I described without any new software.

Comment: yes, I see that now. It's late and I'm tired! Briefly looking through the Word doc it does like it could be what I want. I'll report back tomorrow.