# Using existing user profile again in fresh Windows 7/8 install

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, user-profiles

After installing windows, when there are no accounts (or maybe a temporary account has to be created to do so) can we use a 'profile directory' like (D:\Users\Bilal) which was saved from the previous windows install?

Does doing so, retrieves all windows and softwares' settings?

Comment: Why not use the file and settings transfer?

Comment: files and settings transfer won't transfer app settings or appdata folder. I was just looking at your [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/569691/duplicate-windows-7-user-profile-to-a-new-user) just before this :D

Answer (score 0):

Well, it honestly depends.

Many programs uses the %APPDATA% folder, which would be easily transferable to another HDD/installation, but a few use their own program directories.

You would also have to have the rename the previous directory to suit your needs.
For example, if your user was called 'BillyBob', you would need to name it 'C:\Users\BillyBob'.

And, depending on the program, your PC will need to be named the same too.

Programs that use the Registry to store things like Serials/registration data will also need to be re-registered.

ALSO, something to note, check your *Insert antivirus*'s chest or whatever, because if you move those over to your new system, then they'll no longer be boxed and will be able to infect your system.

Comment: after windows reinstall, if I create a user with same old name and then rename this newly created user directory and put instead the old directory (from the previous install) it doesn't work, I think there are permission issues. Though User name and PC name are exactly the same as previous install